# How to change the shared library searching order?

Tags: c++, linux

When a program needs a shared library (say `libabc.so`), it will first check the path of "-labc", and then the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`， then the `/etc/ld.so.conf` . What should I do if I want the program search the `/etc/ld.so.conf` first?

Comment: What do you mean by "the path of -labc"? In my experience, the -labc is used at link time, together with "-L" options, but then, unless you use some extra-compiler flag, it is completely forgotten. That leaves only LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ld.so.conf... Anyway, if you want to force a very particular symbol in a process, you might use LD_PRELOAD.

Answer (score 1):

Specify it explicitly, in the list of files, before any `-l` option.
Under Unix (including Linux), the libraries are processed in the order
they are given, one after the other.  And whether you specify a library
with the `-l` option or by specifying the actual path doesn't make a
difference; you can invoke g++ with things like:

```
g++ file1.o file2.o ... /etc/ld.so.conf ... -labc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could unset the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

As far as i am concerned the purpose of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is to provide a library which does not exists in your ld.so.conf. Also you have to make sure that a library which you provide by including it in /etc/ld.so.conf is in the cache your  /etc/ld.so.cache. you have do execute

```
ldconfig
```

as super user to update your /etc/ld.so.cache